# What is the use of angle brackets like methodName<string>() in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Can you please help me if there have any tutorial on it why we use the angular brackets <> in type script for example I have given some code here I need explanation.

```
export class HomePage {

     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
         let a = this.testfunc<boolean>(4);
         console.log(a);
     }

     testfunc<T>(s) {
         return s;
     }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are indicating [generics](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). `testfunc<T>(s){ return s; }` means that `testfunc` accepts a generic type parameter `T`. `testfunc<boolean>(4)` provides a type argument (`boolean`) for that type parameter. In that example it doesn't do much of anything since `testfunc` doesn't use `T`, but consider:

```
function foo(arg: string) {
    let numbers: Array<number> = [];
    numbers[0] = arg; // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
}
```

That declares `numbers` as an array of `number`. Since `arg` is a string, you can't do `numbers[0] = arg`.

Compare with:

```
function foo<T>(arg: T) {
    let numbers: Array<T> = [];
    numbers[0] = arg; // Error    
}
```

Now, `foo` doesn't know what `numbers` contains, just that whatever it contains will match the type of `arg`. So both of these calls are valid:

```
foo<number>(4);
foo<string>("bar");
```

I've included the type arguments in those calls for emphasis, but TypeScript can infer them much of the time:

```
foo(4);
foo("bar");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @T.J. Crowder, I try to understand from many days, but now its clear. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Those angular brackets are known as Generics. Generics allow you to define placeholders for the type of fields, methods of a class.
It simply allows the type to be defined at a later time.

```
export class HomePage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    let a = this.testfunc<boolean>(4);
    console.log(a);
}

    testfunc<T>(s){
         return s;
    }
}
```

For your `testFunc` method, you’re simply creating a method that can accept any data type. That `T` in between the angled brackets is called a type argument.

Using generics gives you some sort of freedom you don't get otherwise. For example with a generic method I can pass in any type as its type argument.

function Rand(value: T) {
   ...
}

Setting `T` as a `string` would mean every `T` in that function would have to be a string, same goes for other types.